# the regular expression \p{Punct} misses unicode punctuation in java

Tags: java, regex, unicode

I wrote a little test to demonstrate

```
@Test
public void missingPunctuationRegex() {
    Pattern punct = Pattern.compile("[\\p{Punct}]");

    Matcher m = punct.matcher("'");
    assertTrue("ascii puctuation", m.find());

    m = punct.matcher("‘");
    assertTrue("unicode puctuation", m.find());
}
```

The first assert passes, and the second one fails.  You may have to squint to see it, but that is the 'LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK' ([U+2018](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2018/index.htm)) and should be covered as a punctuation as far as I can tell.

How would I match ALL punctuations in Java regular expressions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS) flag to make `\p{Punct}` match all Unicode punctuation.

Comment: ...assuming you're running Java 7 or later, that is.

Comment: Pattern.compile("[\\p{Punct}]", Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS); makes the test pass.  It seems to work with Java 6 for me.

Comment: I was actually on Java 7.  eclipse just lies.

Answer (score 1):

The [Javadoc of `Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) states

> `\p{Punct}`     Punctuation: One of `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~`

You'll have to match it explicitly as it is not considered as part of `\p{Punct}`.

```
Pattern punct = Pattern.compile("[\\p{Punct}‘]");
```