# Java - Remove all non word characters of a string for all languages

Tags: java, regex, punctuation

I need to remove all punctuation from words in java i tried this

```
    System.out.println("do.,it".replaceAll("[^\\w]", ""));
    System.out.println("сказочники".replaceAll("[^\\w]", ""));
```

But it won't work with kyrillic or other languages. I already tried to work with

```
\p{Punct}
```

But the list is not complete, for example

```
„ and »
```

Are missing

Comment: possible duplicate of [the regular expression \p{Punct} misses unicode punctuation in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000150/the-regular-expression-ppunct-misses-unicode-punctuation-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if java supports this, but have a try with:

```
"сказочники".replaceAll("\P{wd}+", "")
```

where `\P{wd}` stands for any non-word character in any language. It is the opposite of `\p{wd}`

Comment: It didn't work on my Java 1.8 platform. I've used "сказочники".replaceAll("\P{LD}+", "") with success, where LD stands for "any letter or digit".

Answer (score 1):

Try with this regex.

```
 text = text.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "");
```

This will remove all special characters except space.

**Edit:**

As this is a different language.

Suppose you have to remove `- + ^ . : ,`

Try this, `text = text.replaceAll("[\\-\\+\\.\\^:,]","");`

Comment: System.out.println("do.,it".replaceAll("(\\w+)\\p{Punct}(\\s|$)", "$1$2")); prints "do.,it"... and either i don't think it works for kyrillic

Comment: Try the second one mate.

Comment: i don't know why but it seems to work, thanks =) i'll accept it as soon as possible

Comment: how can i include more punctiations like » ?

Comment: Just add inside [?:!.,;]

Comment: does not work for me: System.out.println("сказочники»".replaceAll("([a-z]+)[?:!.,;»]*", "$1"));

Comment: I think you are missing one escape..Try .replaceAll("\\p{Punct}+", "")

Comment: punct only includes !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~... but there arte many more in utf8

Comment: "сказочники»".replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\s]", "") -> gives an empty string

Comment: Those are special characters its treating.

Comment: @wutzebaer I have edited once. I tested the second one. Its working.

Answer (score 1):

my solution seems to be

```
System.out.println("сказ очники»»«„“‚‘›‹".replaceAll("[^\\p{L}]", ""));
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: why is this not the solution? i wrote "I need to remove all punctuation from words in java"

Comment: You're also asking a question. SO is a Q&A forum, you can't end an answer with a question... doesn't make sense :-)